# max-width media query: is document.width or window.width in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, media-queries

I am trying to reproduce media query: max-width: 1024px with javascript and I just misunderstand the difference as I get different values with document.width and window.width

My question is which one is correct or a match, here is my code:

```
if($(document).width() < 1024){
      console.log($(document).width());
      return true;
} else {
      return false;
}
```

In modernizr I would do it like that but I am trying not to use it.

```
if (Modernizr.mq('only all and (max-width: 1024px)')) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: document is the whole page, window is the visible area. Pretty sure you could have googled to find that. A media query should relate to the window width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's window width.

For example, you can make the <body style="width:200000px", so the document width will be 200000px, but the window width is just the browser width(normally won't bigger than your screen), so you will see the horizontal scroll now